# pyenv giving errors after trying to install python 3.6.9

Tags: python, linux

i am currently on Kali Linux and after i wrote "pyenv install python3.6.9" it gave me this:[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv7d1.png) can someone help?

````
BUILD FAILED (Kali 2022.2 using python-build 2.3.3) Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20220804174325.3014
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20220804174325.3014.log
Last 10 log lines:
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
    case upgrade in \
        upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
     ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
make: *** [Makefile:1064: install] Error 139```
````

Comment: BUILD FAILED (Kali 2022.2 using python-build 2.3.3)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20220804174325.3014
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20220804174325.3014.log

Last 10 log lines:
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
 case upgrade in \
  upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
  install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
 esac; \
  ./python -E -m ensurepip \
  $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Segmentation fault
make: *** [Makefile:1102: install] Error 139

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install gcc-10
CC=gcc-10 pyenv install 3.6.9
```